# How to access FTP server in terminal using proxy?

Tags: proxy, ftp, linux-networking, terminal

I have Ubuntu 16.04 installed on my pc. My network require http proxy to access the internet.

Say Proxy is "**xxx.xx.xx.xx**" and port is "**8080**".

I set up system proxy for http, https and ftp. I am able to access internet through terminal. But I am able to access FTP server only in web browser, not in terminal.

When i try to access FTP server, i get :

```
user@hostname:~$ ftp ftp.example.org
ftp: connect to address 213.138.116.78: Connection refused
Trying 2001:41c8:112:8300::15:0...
ftp: connect: Network is unreachable
ftp>
```

It working with VPN.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install lftp. It has an ftp proxy environment variable that you can set to connect through proxy from the command line.
[lftp man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/lftp)

**Example:**

```
user@yourmachine:~$ sudo apt-get install lftp
```

[...]

```
user@yourmachine:~$ lftp
lftp :~> set ftp:proxy http://proxyuser:proxypass@yourproxyIPorHOSTNAME:port 
lftp :~> open ftp.example.com 
lftp :~> USER ftpUSER
password: ftpPASS
```

Comment: I read the lftp man page and tried but i am not able to access. Can you please tell me exactly what should i do ?

Comment: check out the Example after my edit.

Comment: You're welcome. If you think it was helpful mark my answer as solution.

Answer (score 3):

1. Set ftp_proxy in env

   ```
   export ftp_proxy="http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:8080"
   ```
2. After that when you use ftp command, it is auto add proxy server.

   ```
   ftp ftp.example.org
   ```
3. If no longer need proxy.

   ```
   unset ftp_proxy
   ```